# mobile media query messing up desktop version

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

Site-in-progress: http://www.modernfuture.net/wordpress

In my CSS I stylize the landscape mode for my android device (480px) with the following line:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px)
```

This works perfectly if viewing the site on a desktop, but it doesn't work on my android galaxy S3.

However if I change that line of code to

```
@media only screen and (min-width:480px)
```

It looks like I want on my android device (with the exception of the small white space on the right) but it seems that media query's styling gets applied to my desktop version.

It seems as though the media query isn't working right because the CSS that defines the landscape mode won't just apply to my android device - it's either applied to both the desktop version & the android landscape version or none of them. Do I have to set up a separate media query for the desktop width? Or is it something much simpler?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target an S3 you'd need different pixel size to the one in your question

```
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  // your css
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  // your css
}
```